# Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAP

Tags: web-services, soap

Here you can find the WSDL for my Jobs.asmx webService. http://recpushdata.cyndigo.com/jobs.asmx

The Thing is I have created a HTML page at http://bugmusic.cyndigo.com/CallWebService.html

and its returning an Error Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAP.

I am not able to find the bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352174/server-did-not-recognize-the-value-of-http-header-soapaction)

Answer (score 0):

add or remove the httppost, httpget protocols. like below:

in your Web.config

```
&lt;webServices&gt;<br>
&lt;protocols&gt;<br>
&lt;add name=&quot;HttpPost&quot;/&gt; <br>
&lt;add name=&quot;HttpGet&quot;/&gt; <br>
&lt;/protocols&gt;<br>
&lt;/webServices&gt;<br>

in your machine.config:<br>
&lt;system.web&gt;<br>
    ...<br>
    &lt;webServices&gt;<br>
        &lt;protocols&gt;<br>
              &lt;add name="HttpSoap"/&gt;<br>
              &lt;add name="HttpPost"/&gt;<br>
              &lt;add name="HttpGet"/&gt;<br>
              &lt;add name="Documentation"/&gt;<br>
              &lt;add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/&gt;<br>
        &lt;/protocols&gt;<br>
    &lt;/webServices&gt;<br>
    ...<br>
&lt;/system.web<br>
```

Comment: I guess your Answer is Incomplete