# Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services

```
   [SoapRpcMethod(Action = "http://cyberindigo/TempWebService/InsertXML",
    RequestNamespace = "http://cyberindigo/TempWebService/Request",
    RequestElementName = "InsertXMLRequest",
    ResponseNamespace = "http://cyberindigo/TempWebService/Response",
    ResponseElementName = "InsertXMLResponse",
    Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]

    [WebMethod]
    public string InsertXML(string Jobs)
    {
        return "Hi";
    }
```

The Problem when I am accessing it using XMLHttpRequest it gives following error 
Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://Cyberindigo/TempWebService/InsertXML

Answer (score 84):

The source of the next part of this post is:

> http://bluebones.net/2003/07/server-did-not-recognize-http-header-soapaction/

(since the OP didn't want to give attribution, and thanks to Peter)

Please note that bakert is the original author of the text, not the OP.

---

Seeing as nowhere on the internet can I find an explanation of this error I thought I’d share the fruits of my long search for this bug.

It means (at least in my case) that you are accessing a web service with SOAP and passing a `SOAPAction` parameter in the HTTP request that does not match what the service is expecting.

I got in a pickle because we moved a web service from one server to another and thus I changed the “namespace” (don’t get confused between web service namespaces and .net namespaces) in the calling C# file to match the new server. But the server doesn’t care about the actual web reality of `http://yournamespace.com/blah` it only cares that you send it what you have said you are expecting on the server. It doesn’t care if there’s actually anything there or not.

So basically the web service was moved from `http://foo.com/servicename` to `http://bar.com/servicename` but the “namespace” of the web service stayed as `http://foo.com/servicename` because no one changed it.

And that only took about 4 hours to work out!

If you’re having a similar problem but can’t work what I’m saying here, feel free to mail me on bakert+web@gmail.com – I wouldn’t wish my four hours on anyone!

Comment: I had a similar problem where the Web Reference had gotten out of date with the Service. Updating the Web Reference in Visual Studio cleaned it up.

Comment: It is interesting to me that people bump up against this one 9 years later.  I get a couple of emails about this every month thanks to my blog post.  Thanks for the attribution jcolebrand :)

Comment: In my company, we have multiple installations of a web service, because it's an internal web application that some clients have installed locally.  We picked a random namespace, because the URL changed with each client.  Oddly, I've NEVER seen this error before today.  EVER.  It's happened on a development server when the web service was rewritten in a newer version of .NET.  Apparently the web service namespace doesn't have to be the same as the URL, and the team that was rewriting the service changed the namespace.

Comment: If anyone worked with SharePoint UDCLibrary: We got "SoapAction value is invalid" after moved an asmx to another sever. Fixed by keeping the same: <udc:SoapAction>http://oldserver/L/GetSomeMethod</udc:SoapAction>

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  I have tried changing my namespace to no avail.  What do I change?  This?  `[WebService(Namespace = "https://localhost:44391/")]` in my `class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService`?

Answer (score 8):

While calling the .asmx / wcf web service please take care of below points:

1. The namespace is case sensitive,the SOAP request MUST be sent with the same namespace with which the WebService is declared.

e.g. For the WebService declared as below

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://MyDomain.com/TestService")] 
public class FooClass : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
   [WebMethod]   
    public bool Foo( string name)    
     {

      ...... 
     }

 }
```

The SOAP request must maintain the same case for namespace while calling.Sometime we overlook the case sensitivity.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
     <Foo xmlns="http://MyDomain.com/TestService">
     <name>string</name>      
     </Foo>
  </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

2. The namespace need not be same as hosted url of the service.The namespace can be any string.

e.g. Above service may be hosted at http://84.23.9.65/MyTestService , but still while invoking the Web Service from client the namespace should be the same which the serice class is having i.e.http://MyDomain.com/TestService

Comment: "The namespace need not be same as hosted url of the service.The namespace can be any string." ... OK, now I understand why this only started happening to us.  Another team rewrote the web service in a newer version of .NET.  They must have changed the namespace.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Sam in that the SOAP definition does not match what is expected. Here is just ONE solution it could be, I had to manually figure this error for myself:

My problem was that I changed the name of the web method but did not change the "MessageName" in the metadata tag.

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "foo")]
public string bar()
{

}
```

It should be

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "foo")]
public string foo()
{

}
```

hope that helps someone

Answer (score 5):

I've decided to post my own answer here because I've lost a few hours on this and I think that, although the accepted answer is very good and pointed me in the right direction (yes, it got a voteup), it was not detailed enough to explain what was wrong with my application, at least in my case.

I'm running a BPEL module in OpenESB 2.2 and the Test Case of my Composite Application was failing with the following error:

> Caused by: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .

After doing some research I've noticed that the external WSDL has all the clues we need to fix this problem, e.g., I'm using the following web service to validate a credit card number through a orchestration of Web Services:
http://www.webservicex.net/CreditCard.asmx?WSDL

If you check the `<wsdl:operation` elements you will see that it clearly states the `soapAction` for that operation:

```
<wsdl:binding name="CCCheckerSoap" type="tns:CCCheckerSoap">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="ValidateCardNumber">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webservicex.net/ValidateCardNumber" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
...
```

But, once you create the Composite Application and build the project with the BPEL that invokes this external WSDL service, for some reason (bug?), the XML of the Composite Application Service Assembly (CASA) binding is generated with an empty `soapAction` parameter:

```
<binding name="casaBinding1" type="ns:CCCheckerSoap">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="ValidateCardNumber">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
```

Once you copy the proper soapAction (http://www.webservicex.net/ValidateCardNumber) into this parameter, the application's Test Case will correctly and return the expected Soap response.

```
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webservicex.net/ValidateCardNumber" style="document"/>
```

So, it's a more specific solution that I decided to document based on the information found in this blog post: http://bluebones.net/2003/07/server-did-not-recognize-http-header-soapaction/.

> It means (at least in my case) that you are accessing a web service
> with SOAP and **passing a SOAPAction parameter in the HTTP request
> that does not match what the service is expecting**.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, it fixed after some checking:

**<< Target WebService Exists but called method's not eXXXists. >>**

> my local service contain methods but target server(connecting server)
>   does not contain specified called method.

**Check your program scenario again...**

Comment: My error was fixed. because of incorrect create/use of web method.
please check 0 to 100 of your code, you can find it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just to help someone on this problem, after an afternoon of debug, the problem was that the web service was developed with framework 4.5 and the call from android must be done with SoapEnvelope.VER12 and not with SoapEnvelope.VER11

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. To debug the problem, I've run [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and capture request generated by my code. Then I used [XML Spy trial](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xml_editor.html) to create a SOAP request (assuming you have WSDL) and compared those two.

This should give you a hint what goes wrong.

Comment: Other tools you could use to do the same thing would be Fiddler and/or SoapUI.

Comment: I used this method (Fiddler) and found that I was hitting an old copy of my web service which didn't include my new method.  My Web.Config was pointing to an old server still.  Blech.

Answer (score 2):

My error fixed by answer Mr. John Saunders : http://forums.asp.net/post/2906487.aspx

in short: difference between Namespace of ws
**.asmx.cs** with ws
**.wsdl** files.

```
1) [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
```

later web service namespace changed to :

```
2) [WebService(Namespace = "http://newvalue.com/")]
```

so we referenced (1) in application and web service is (2) now.

make them equal to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, but the solution for me was that I was pointing to the wrong web service. I had updated the web reference correctly. But we store the URl for the service in an encrypted file, and I didn't update the file with the correct service encrypted.

But all these suggestions really helped me to realize where to go for debugging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after changing the namespace from "tempuri" in my Web Service.

You have to update your Service Reference in the project that is consuming the above service, so it can get the latest SOAP definitions.

Or at least that worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

We had renamed some of our webservice project namespaces and forgot to update the website httphandlers config section with the namespace of the renamed projects.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, i was able to resolve it by removing the 'Web Reference' and adding a 'Service Reference' instead

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I tried to call a method which did not exist. It only existed in a newer version of our webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I had to sort out capitalisation of my service reference, delete the references and re add them to fix this. I am not sure if any of these steps are superstitious, but the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the same error message:

`System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:` Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header `SOAPAction`:

We utilize dynamic URL's in our web service calls.  We have a central configuration server that manages the location of all web service calls so that our code can run in DEV, test or live without recompiling.  The URL for a specific web service call for the test environment was incorrect in our configuration server.  The web service call was being sent to the wrong server and the wrong web service.

So this error can simply be the result of the web service request not matching the web service being called.

It took running fiddler on the Web App server to see that the actual call was to the incorrect web service.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute
in the service. Please check it. it may changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my web reference was out of date and the code was calling a removed web service.