# Soap Exception in ASMX service after publishing via Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I've got a strange problem regarding ASP.NET ASMX webservices. I have a webservice providing some method "GetLicencedApplications". The service is already used by a client application and worked fine. The service code has not been changed for a while. Some days ago, I used the visual studio "Publish..." functionality to deploy a copy of the webservice to a test server.

Since that moment, the service doesn't work on my developer machine anymore. When I'm connection with my client application to the localhost test URL of the webservice, I always get the following exception:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize
>   the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:
>   http://soa.oursite.com/ourApp/licencing/GetLicencedApplications.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
>   (...)

Has anyone experienced similar problems? I've already tried to update the web service reference within my client application, but this did not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction C# Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352174/server-did-not-recognize-the-value-of-http-header-soapaction-c-sharp-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if the Namespace for your web service has changed? 
The value is a case-sensitive string and given your exception, I would expect the value to be:
[WebService(Namespace = "http://soa.oursite.com/ourApp/licencing/")]