# SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am getting error with Soap. I have tried so much but I am not able to solve this problem. Everything is fine but then also don't know what is the wrong.

I am getting perfect result of `WebsiteURL`, `NameSpace` and `MethodName`.
**Logcat:**

```
03-09 12:59:04.190: W/System.err(3081): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: BecomeExpert.
03-09 12:59:04.190: W/System.err(3081):    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
03-09 12:59:04.200: W/System.err(3081):    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
03-09 12:59:04.200: W/System.err(3081):    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
03-09 12:59:04.300: W/System.err(3081):    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@40d11120
03-09 12:59:04.330: W/System.err(3081):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:112)
03-09 12:59:04.361: W/System.err(3081):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
03-09 12:59:04.460: W/System.err(3081):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)


03-09 13:09:29.249: W/System.err(3407):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:112)
03-09 13:09:29.309: W/System.err(3407):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
03-09 13:09:29.309: W/System.err(3407):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
03-09 13:09:29.309: W/System.err(3407):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
03-09 13:09:29.349: W/System.err(3407):     at com.band.seekersstop.BecomeExpert$BecomeExpertTask.doInBackground(BecomeExpert.java:398)
03-09 13:09:29.399: W/System.err(3407):     at com.band.seekersstop.BecomeExpert$BecomeExpertTask.doInBackground(BecomeExpert.java:1)
03-09 13:09:29.399: W/System.err(3407):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-09 13:09:29.409: W/System.err(3407):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-09 13:09:29.409: W/System.err(3407):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-09 13:09:29.449: W/System.err(3407):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-09 13:09:29.490: W/System.err(3407):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1):

That means that the web service doesn't support a method called "BecomeExpert", or there's a problem with the definition of the web service.

An example of the latter is shown in [Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352174/server-did-not-recognize-the-value-of-http-header-soapaction)

Comment: but BecomeExpert() method is there and it is working fine on Webservice. Then also I am gonna to try it by another name.

Comment: I have also tried another method name but still getting same error with that new method name.