# Android: Error while trying to access a .Net Web Service

Tags: java, android, .net, web-services

I have created a small app to access a .Net Web Service

But I get this error from Android

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://webservice.pollsdb.com/Msgs.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@b1ebfe80
```

does anyone know how to call this service from android?

This is my code

```
SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;

request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);

//Adding String value to request object
request.addProperty("Lg", Lg);
request.addProperty("Lt", Lt);
request.addProperty("Cnt", Cnt);

//request.addProperty("ToUnit", "" + toUnit);

SetEnvelope();

//SOAP calling webservice
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

//Got Webservice response
String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();

return result;
```

Comment: did u already checkd this topic? hope it helps > http://stackoverflow.com/q/352174/3640637

Comment: yes i saw this, but did not know how to will help in my case, i am very new to android and java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem
It was in the .Net not in the Android
Just changed the Namespace from .Net default to the website where the service is

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://webservice.pollsdb.com/")]
```