# Problems with SOAPAction: server did not recognize the value of http header SOAPAction

Tags: c#, .net, asmx, soap-client, webservice-client

I've been facing lots of problem with a WebService implementation. I know that this website has some topics related with it, but I've tried the steps I've found and nothing work to me.

I created a .NET WebService that will be called by QAD ERP. I've installed the Web Service on our server that can be accessed by the following address: 187.72.208.85/qadws/QADXmlWS.asmx

The ERP is calling the Web Service sending the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header></soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<qdoc:Item xmlns:qdoc="http://187.72.208.85/QADWs/QADXmlWs/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<qdoc:file>
<qdoc:operation>A</qdoc:operation>
<qdoc:ptAdded>2015-06-09</qdoc:ptAdded>
<qdoc:ptCdCmmt/>
<qdoc:ptCdRef>DI</qdoc:ptCdRef>    
</qdoc:file>
</qdoc:Item>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The web service code is:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://187.72.208.85/QADWs/QADXmlWs/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class QADXmlWs : System.Web.Services.WebService
{       
    [WebMethod]
    public void Item(byte[] file)
    {                   
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:/ws/Item.xml", file);           
    }
}
```

When I call Web Service, it gives me the following error:

```
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP SOAPAction: 'http://187.72.208.85/QADWs/QADXmlWs/Item'.</faultstring>
<detail />
</soap:Fault>
```

I don't have any idea how I can solve this problem. 
Could you help me out with this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352174/server-did-not-recognize-the-value-of-http-header-soapaction)

Comment: it didn't work to me! :(